# Unknown URL while applying schematic library in Content Provider

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to add a content provider in my app but it is showing URL not found.I tried to add  tag in Android Manifest file and made the authority address to my package address but still the result is same .There is a database and contract java file also but the problem is in FCMprovider.java only.Please help

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fcm.bio.fcm/fcm.bio.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://fcm.bio.ayushsharma.fcm.provider.provider/messages
```

FCMprovider.java

```
@ContentProvider(
    authority = FCMprovider.AUTHORITY,
    database = FCMdatabase.class
)

public class FCMprovider {
public static final String 
AUTHORITY="fcm.bio.ayushsharma.fcm.provider.provider";

@TableEndpoint(table = FCMdatabase.FCM_MESSAGES)
public static class FCMmessages{
    @ContentUri(
            path = "messages",
            type="vnd.android.cursor.dir/message",
            defaultSort = FCMcontract.COLUMN_DATE+"DESC")
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI=Uri.parse("content://"+ AUTHORITY + "/messages");
}

}
```

AndroidManifest.java

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <provider
        android:authorities="com.bio.ayushsharma.fcm.provider.provider"
        android:name=".provider.generated.FCMprovider"
        android:exported="false"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".following.followingPreferenceActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
</application>
```

mainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private static String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int LOADER_ID_MESSAGES = 0;

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
SquawkAdapter mAdapter;

static final String[] MESSAGES_PROJECTION = {
        SquawkContract.COLUMN_AUTHOR,
        SquawkContract.COLUMN_MESSAGE,
        SquawkContract.COLUMN_DATE,
        SquawkContract.COLUMN_AUTHOR_KEY
};

static final int COL_NUM_AUTHOR = 0;
static final int COL_NUM_MESSAGE = 1;
static final int COL_NUM_DATE = 2;
static final int COL_NUM_AUTHOR_KEY = 3;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.squawks_recycler_view);

    // Use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // Use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // Add dividers
    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(
            mRecyclerView.getContext(),
            mLayoutManager.getOrientation());
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

    // Specify an adapter
    mAdapter = new SquawkAdapter();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Start the loader
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID_MESSAGES, null, this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_following_preferences) {
        // Opens the following activity when the menu icon is pressed
        Intent startFollowingActivity = new Intent(this, FollowingPreferenceActivity.class);
        startActivity(startFollowingActivity);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


/**
 * Loader callbacks
 */

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    // This method generates a selection off of only the current followers
    String selection = SquawkContract.createSelectionForCurrentFollowers(
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Selection is " + selection);
    return new CursorLoader(this, SquawkProvider.SquawkMessages.CONTENT_URI,
            MESSAGES_PROJECTION, selection, null, SquawkContract.COLUMN_DATE + " DESC");
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
android:authorities="com.bio.ayushsharma.fcm.provider.provider"
```

This begins with `com.`

```
AUTHORITY="fcm.bio.ayushsharma.fcm.provider.provider";
```

This begins with `fcm`.

These are not the same, and they need to be the same. So, change one or the other.